# How to write PHP array to render JSON-LD Markup for Job Postings, with ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, array, json

i want to add a dynamic JSON-LD (schema.org) for career posts in my wordpress page. I tried this code below. But i think i have some Syntax errors within the array. Maybe the "echo" is not allowed within the array? I hope somebody can help me with this?

```
<?php function schema() {?>

<?php if( have_rows('schema_auszeichnung') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('schema_auszeichnung') ): the_row(); 

        // Get sub field values.
        $title = get_sub_field('title');
        $description = get_sub_field('description');
        $state = get_sub_field('state');
        $date = get_sub_field('date');
        $street = get_sub_field('street');
        $city = get_sub_field('city');
        $postalcode = get_sub_field('postalcode');


$schema = array(
    '@context'  => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type'     => 'JobPosting',
    'title'      => $title,
    'description' => $description,
    'hiringOrganization'   => array(
        '@type'           => 'Organization',
        'name'            => 'cent GmbH',
        'sameAs'          => get_home_url(),
        'logo'            => '/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-logo.png'

    ),

    'employmentType'=> $state,
    'datePosted'    => $date,
    'validThrough'  => "",
    'jobLocation'   => array(

        '@type'     =>  "Place",
        'address'   => array (

            '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
            'streetAddress' => $street,
            'adressLocality' => $city,
            'postalCode' => $postalcode,
            'addressCountry' => 'DE'


        ),
    ),     


);

?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php


echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema) . '</script>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'schema');

?>
```

EDIT:

After removing the 'echo' i got the php warning: Undefined variable: schema. But for me it is defined in this line: $schema = array.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems more like a PHP programming question, but yes as you guessed in PHP if you want the value of a variable you just need `$var`. `echo $var` outputs it and will cause a syntax error how you've used it.

Otherwise everything else looks ok, although obviously I can't say if that data structure will give you valid JSON-LD ;-)

EDIT: Also it's good to give your functions a more unique name than `'schema'`. You could call it `'yourname_jsonld_schema'` or something, so that it's much more unique and unlikely to collide with any other names in Wordpress

EDIT2: To address the extra error you added to your question, the place you define `$schema` is *inside* an `if` statement, which means that if the variable is not defined later, that `if` was not true. So you need to do something like figure out why the `if` is false, or if it's correct, put the place where you use the `$schema` inside the `if` too.

Comment: thanks for your answer... but also without 'echo' i got to many errors... do you see something else?

Comment: You need to add the specific errors you're seeing to your question, otherwise it's impossible to help

Comment: i edited the my question

Comment: @tom84 updated the answer, see edit2

Comment: thanks! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for this! I was trying to solve almost the same problem, but to pull ACF from an FAQ page and add a structured data page for rich snippets when people google us: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/faqpage

Below is my solution

```
<?php

$faq_page_schema = '';

if( have_rows('questions') ):
    while ( have_rows('questions') ) : the_row();
        $question = '"'.get_sub_field('question').'"';
        $answer = '"'.get_sub_field('answer').'"';
        $faq_page_schema .= "{
            \"@type\": \"Question\",
            \"name\": $question,
            \"acceptedAnswer\": {
                \"@type\": \"Answer\",
                \"text\": $answer
            }
        }, ";
    endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;

$faq_page_schema = substr_replace($faq_page_schema ,"", -2);

echo
'<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "FAQPage",
        "mainEntity": ['.$faq_page_schema.']
    }
</script>';

?>
```